# Angular ngx-translate, does not translate first time

Tags: angular, browser, browser-cache, ngx-translate

I use ngx-translate with angular. When the site is opened on a new pc, the translation does not show, only the keys. Then the user have to press F5 for it to translate. Happens every time as far as I know. Sometimes when I haven't touched to project in a while, I get the same issue on my pc.

I want to debug and test if the translation file is not downloaded and initialized at the time the page is shown, but it proves very difficult, because I can't get it in the state of not translating anymore after I reloaded the page. Just keeps being translated.

I tried to:

- Clean all browser cache at "all time"
- Use the Edge browser
- Uninstall and reinstall Chrome browser
- Install another browser (Opera)
- Restart pc
- Recompile the project in VS code

It just stays translated and I haven't done anything to make it work, even saw it first time I switched to the project at localhost today, so I know it's not working as expected.

I need it to come in an untranslated state or else I won't know what I'm looking for and can't verify that is working after I try to fix it.

**Does anyone have an idea what I could try?**

In App.module in imports I do:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
```

In App.module in providers I do:

```
{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initTranslations,
      deps: [TranslateService],
      multi: true,
    },
```

The translation methods:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

export function initTranslations(
  translateService: TranslateService,
): () => Promise<any> {
  return () => {
    const supportedLanguages = ['en'];
    const defaultLanguage = 'en';

    translateService.addLangs(supportedLanguages);
    translateService.setDefaultLang(defaultLanguage);
    const browserLang = translateService.getBrowserLang();
    const language =
      supportedLanguages.find((x) => x === browserLang) ?? defaultLanguage;
    return translateService.use(language).toPromise();
  };
}
```

Comment: disable browser caching won't reproduce it?

Comment: No not working sadly

Comment: really strange. Probably still some browser chache related issue. Had the ngx-translate also sometimes failing for me. Just an idea, if it won't happen for you also the connection speed could have a role. For you localy it's loaded instantly but for someone else not. May the page gets just rendered before the tranlations get loaded and the view doesn't get loaded. On the next loads the translation files should be chached and load instantly. So may force a view rendering after loading (e.g. with NgZone.Run(()=>....)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't know why yet, but the first time translate didn't load the default language.

On first run, the following code always displays null

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    ...
    public translate: TranslateService,
    ...
  ) {
    ...
    const currentLang = this.translate.currentLang;
    console.log(currentLang);
    ...
  }
```

I solved the problem by forcing to my default language

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    ...
    public translate: TranslateService,
    ...
  ) {
    ...
    this.translate.use('pt');
    ...
  }
```

I believe there is a more efficient solution.